# BigQuery: How to make FULL JOIN with multiple tables ON multiple keys without losing data?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have been struggling with this issue in BigQuery for a while now and can't find a solution for it.
I have 3 tables with campaign costs that I need to join together in a single table, here are some examples below of what the tables look like:

### Table 1

| Date | Country | Costs Campaign A |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-06-01 | Argentina | 10 |
| 2021-06-01 | Brazil | 30 |
| 2021-06-01 | Colombia | 10 |
| 2021-06-02 | Argentina | 50 |
| 2021-06-02 | Brazil | 65 |
| 2021-06-02 | Colombia | 40 |

### Table 2

| Date | Country | Costs Campaign B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-06-01 | Argentina | 54 |
| 2021-06-01 | Brazil | 38 |
| 2021-06-01 | Germany | 94 |
| 2021-06-02 | Argentina | 51 |
| 2021-06-02 | Brazil | 48 |
| 2021-06-02 | Germany | 88 |

### Table 3

| Date | Country | Costs Campaign C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-06-01 | Argentina | 27 |
| 2021-06-01 | Brazil | 55 |
| 2021-06-01 | Poland | 46 |
| 2021-06-02 | Argentina | 86 |
| 2021-06-02 | Brazil | 99 |
| 2021-06-02 | Poland | 47 |

My output should look like this in the end

| Date | Country | Costs Campaign A | Costs Campaign B | Costs Campaign C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-06-01 | Argentina | 10 | 54 | 27 |
| 2021-06-01 | Brazil | 30 | 38 | 55 |
| 2021-06-01 | Colombia | 10 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-06-01 | Germany | 0 | 94 | 0 |
| 2021-06-01 | Poland | 0 | 0 | 46 |
| 2021-06-02 | and so on... | x | y | z |

And here is a similar query to the one I've been trying:

```
SELECT
  t1.Date,
  t1.Country,
  SUM(t1.CostsCampaignA),
  SUM(t2.CostsCampaignB),
  SUM(t3.CostsCampaignC)
FROM `table1` AS t1
FULL JOIN `table2` AS t2 ON t1.Date = t2.Date AND t1.Country = t2.Country
FULL JOIN `table3` AS t3 ON t1.Date = t3.Date AND t1.Country = t3.Country
GROUP BY 1,2
```

Now my problem is that for the countries not present in table 1, they do not appear in my output at all (in the example, Germany and Poland). I would assume that the FULL JOIN would ensure that no data gets lost, but this is not the case.

I would appreciate if anyone has a solution for my issue or any suggestions for a workaround.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select * from (
  select date, country, cost_campaign_a as cost, 'A' campaign from table_1 
  union all select date, country, cost_campaign_b, 'B' from table_2 
  union all select date, country, cost_campaign_c, 'C' from table_3 
)
pivot (any_value(cost) cost_campaign for campaign in ('A', 'B', 'C'))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]